# Compare data from MS SQL and MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'd like to compare 2 queries results in order to get non corresponding data.

I have a MS SQL server that is linked to a MySQL server.

My first query get the emails and the number associated to it on MS SQL database:

```
select email, number  from [DB].[dbo].[Contacts];
```

My second query get the emails and the number associated to it on MySQL database:

```
select email, number from database.contacts;
```

I know that I can run a query on MySQL from MS SQL by using this kind of query:

```
SET @SQLStr = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([DB-01],''select email, number from database.contacts'')'
EXEC(@SQLStr)
```

But I have no idea of how to read and compare the results.

I'd like to know if email and number association existing in MS SQL database is different in MySQL server.

i.e.:
if email = 'eee@eee.com' and number = 00222 on MS SQL 
but email 'eee@eee.com and number = 012325 on MySQL, I want to get the second result that is different.

Comment: What comparison do you want to do, and what is the expected output, if any?

Comment: I have edited the question to add the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using dynamic SQL when there's nothig dynamic about it?

You can use standard query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([DB-01],'select email, number from database.contacts')
```

With your SQL Server query you'll get two resultsets.

To compare results you could use `EXCEPT`, to get records from one table not existing in another table.

Other way is to use `OUTER JOIN~and see if any records have`NULL`s meaning that there is no match in the other table.